# Использование экспортируемых из exe функций

Tags: c++, winapi, dll

Насколько мне известно **exe** и **dll** это по сути одно и тоже, только в **dll** есть *таблица экспорта*. Ранее я пробовал экспортировать из **exe** что-то простенькое(вроде  `Sleep()`). Сейчас появилась в этом нужда, но всё усложнилось. Что происходит:

Я подгружаю экзешник из другого экзешника с помощью `LoadLibrary()`(`GetLastError()`возвращает 0), получаю ф-цию `GetProcAdress()`(`GetLastError()` всё также выдаёт ноль). В экзешнике, который экспортирует, примерно такой код

```
extern"C" _declspec(dllexport) void go();

static int a=0;

void go()
{
a=1;
}
```

Собственно вопрос:

Если **exe** с экспортируемой ф-ей уже запущен, и я его подгружаю из второго **exe** и вызываю `go()`, то изменится ли в уже запущенном процессе переменная `а`?

Comment: ну а чего руками-то не проверить?

Comment: @strangeqargo, функция не вызывается

Comment: кстати, вопрос, а чего нет в dll, что есть в exe?

Comment: @strangeqargo, Вы спрашиваете, почему я не исользую длл? Екзе хочу юзать как сервер

Comment: вы сказали, что между exe и dll разницы почти нет, я просто спрашиваю, чем exe отличается от dll кроме наличия в dll таблицы экспорта

Comment: @strangeqargo, это всё что я знаю(согласно Мсдн)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нет.

Если вы подгружаете модуль, то у вас будет подгружен на самом деле отдельный экземпляр модуля, не имеющий отношения к этому же модулю как части другого процесса. Каждый процесс будет иметь свой набор статических переменных.

(Тут нету разницы между exe и dll, так что с dll было бы то же самое.)

Comment: Ага, понял. Ну тогда `WM_COPYDATA`